# Write a recursive function, len

Tags: python

Write a recursive function, len, that accepts a parameter that holds a string value, and returns the number of characters in the string.
The length of the string is:

0 if the string is empty ("")

1 more than the length of the string beyond the first character

---

This is what I got so far:

```
def len(string):
 if len(string) == ""
  return 0
 else:
  return string[len(string)+1]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len()` is supposed to return an integer. I think they're looking for something like this:

```
def len(string):
    if string == "":
        # 0 if the string is empty
        return 0
    else:
        # one more than the length of the string beyond the first character
        return 1 + len(string[1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to reduce the problem on your recursive call.  You programmed an infinite recursion.  The critical statement is to recur on a *shorter* string:

```
return len(string[1:]) + 1
```